# Check if string in list contain all the elements from another list

Tags: python, list, contains

I have two lists and I want to check if my list of strings contains all the elements of the second list.

I would like it to return `True` only if all the elements in `list2` are in substrings of elements in `list1` (`True` in this example).

Here is my code :

```py
list1 = ['banana.two', 'apple.three', 'raspberry.six']
list2 = ['two', 'three']
        
if all(elem in elem in list1.tolist() for elem in list2):
```

Comment: What is `tolist`? There is no such list method and doesn't really seem necessary to have one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
list1 = ['banana.two', 'apple.three', 'raspberry.six']
list2 = ['two', 'three']


def check(strings, substrings):
    for substring in substrings:
        if not (any(substring in string for string in strings)):
            return False
    return True


print(check(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You need to combine [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) according to this: *check that **all** strings in `list2` appear in **any** string in `list1`*. Directly translates to:

```py
list1 = ['banana.two', 'apple.three', 'raspberry.six']
list2 = ['two', 'three']

if all(any(sub in string for string in list1) for sub in list2):
    print("Success!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substring = [i for e in list2 for i in list1 if e in i]
if len(susbstring) != 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: It returns True if one of list2 elements is in list1. Not only if all the elements are in list1.